# How to access Vue Component from plain vanilla DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs2, vue-router

## Situation

I'm building a SPA with Vue.
There are pop-up notifications, made with Vue-Noty ( https://github.com/renoguyon/vuejs-noty ).

I have a vuex action, checking session status, if it finds out the session is expired, there will be a noty displayed ("Your Session has expired").
Now i want to add a link ("Login here"), but i'm facing a

## Problem

It is *possible* to add `<a>` tags to the notification. they work fine too.

but Vue SPAs don't like plain `<a>` tags of course...

I need to have a `<router-link>`. but that doesn't "just" work, it has to be parsed out of a .vue file to generate an `<a>` which works for single-page-navigation.

Noty CAN handle tags, but if i just add it to the Noty like

```
this._vm.$noty.error('Your Session has expired, please <router-link to="/login">log in again</router-link>.')
```

, it will of course come out as a literal `<router-link>` tag, which will not work.

So my next thought was to put an `<a>` there with an `onClick="this.$router.push('/login')"`

Of course, this also doesn't work, because there is no `this`in a plain DOM element.

My next thought was: maybe i can access the vue router via `window.document`, but i didn't find a way to do it

## Question

How can i call the `$router.push` method from *outside* the vue component or instance, from the "plain DOM"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
app.__vue__.$router.push({'name' : 'home'})
```

Comment: there is no `app` on my global scope e: but WOW, that works. (tried it via devtools first, it didn't work. then i just pasted it into my onClick, and it DOES work. can you explain why? and why i don't see `app` in devtools?