# How to call vue router push method from vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## Problem

I'm trying to dynamically create a clickable image in a d3.js network (using svg elements) in a Vue component method like this :

```
<g>
  <a xlink:href="[go_to_another_vue]">
    <image x="-15" y="-15" height="25" width="25" xlink:href="image.png"></image>
  </a>
</g>
```

I'm using vue 2.6.11, router 3.5.2, vuetify 2.5.8

## Question

How to use Vue router to navigate to another view in this kind of dynamically generated link ?

I found another post with an answer that should work : [How to access Vue Component from plain vanilla DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813688/how-to-access-vue-component-from-plain-vanilla-dom)
and tried to set the href attribute to
`javascript:app.__vue__.$router.push({path:'[path_to_another_vue]'})` :

```
...
const node = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(nodes)
  .join("g")
  .call(drag(simulation));
node
  .append("a")
  .attr("xlink:href", (d) => `javascript:app.__vue__.$router.push({path:'${this.$route.path}/${d.url}'})`)        
  .append("image")
  .attr("x", -15)
  .attr("y", -15)
  .attr("height", 25)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("xlink:href", (d) => d.image);
```

But the `app.__vue__.$router.push(...)` solution doesn't work for me. It changes the current location (`window.location.href` is ok) but I get a blank page, nothing is loaded, no network activity/no error in devtools.

Any idea of what's wrong ?

Comment: You could try to wrap the image with a <router-link> instead of a regular anchor tag:  https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link

Comment: @felgro I can't do that, `<router-link>` element will appear "as-is" in dom because it is generated by `node.append()` d3.js method

Comment: Maybe this route path is not configured in the router. Are you sure there is a Vue component that matches this route path?